# Why is the value of a shadowed variable not modified in a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, rust

I am not sure why the value of the shadowed variable `foo` is not being modified in the `for` loop:

```
fn main() {
    let foo: i32 = 5;
    for _x in 0..5 {
        let foo = foo + 1;
    }
    println!("Value of foo: {}", foo);
    //This prints Value of foo: 5

    let bar: i32 = 5;
    let bar = bar + 1;
    println!("Value of bar: {}", bar);
    //This prints Value of foo: 6
}
```

I went through the [Variables and Mutability section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch03-01-variables-and-mutability.html#shadowing) and some Stack Overflow questions but I could not find the reason why the value of `foo` is not being modified.

I see the same behavior in a `loop`.

1. Do `for` and `loop` have some restrictions on shadowing variables? Why is it not allowed?
2. If shadowing a variable is not a good practice in loops, should I be using a `mut`able variable?

I am using Rust 1.42.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`let` "introduces/creates a new variable".

Thus, `let foo = foo+1;` creates a new variable called "foo" that lives only inside the loop. This variable is initialized to `foo+1`, and only the "right-hand-side `foo`" refers to the already existing `foo`.

Thus, only the "inner-loop `foo`" is created, and the outer `foo` is not touched by the loop.

If you want to modify the outer `foo`, try this:

```
let mut foo: i32 = 5; // mut tells rust that variable is going to be modified
for _x in 0..5{
    foo = foo+1; // no "let", so not introducing a new variable
}
println!("Value of foo: {}", foo);
```

On the other hand, `let bar=bar+1` creates a new variable `bar` in the same scope as the previous `bar`, so the first `bar` is shadowed by the new `bar` and basically cannot be accessed anymore.

Comment: So in the first step of the loop, I get that `let foo = foo + 1` gets the value of `foo` from the outside scope and then creates a new variable in the loop-block scope. But why wouldn't it, in the second iteration, grab the `foo` from the inside scope?

Comment: @Lagerbaer The scope is "per-iteration" (not sure if the scientific term is "lexical").

Comment: Oh that makes sense then. So in the example with `let foo =...` in the loop, there's actually no "within the same scope shadowing" going on. Just "using the same name in an inner scope" shadowing, and that means after the loop, I could happily keep using `foo`.